# PHP MySQL - How easy way to update the database when one or more fields value changed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem on database update activity.

**Case study**:

I created a form with PHP editing, and perform queries to retrieve the value of a record that wants to be updated. Excerpts of the script:

```
<?php
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id, field_1, field_2 FROM mytable WHERE id = $editid"));
?>

 ...

<form action="" method="post">
  FIELD 1 <input type = "text" name = "f1v" value = "<? Php echo $ row ['field_1'];?>" />
  FIELD 2 <input type = "text" name = "f2v" value = "<? Php echo $ row ['field_2'];?>" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

....
// When the form posted

if ($_POST)
{
   $f1v = $ _POST['f1v'];
   $f2v = $ _POST['f2v'];

   mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET field_1 = '$f1v', field_2 = '$f2v' WHERE id = $editid") or die ();

   // Redirect form
}
```

In this case I want when the form submited, there are activities to check whether there is a change in one or more fields values. Its logic approximately like this:

```
if ($ _POST)
{    
    // Compare
   if the submitted value is different from the existing value in the record
   {
      Updated record
   }
   else
   {
      Do not update record
   }       
    // Redirect form
}
```

Do you have any easy way to do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not just update the record anyway; if the new value is the same as the old value, it won't have any effect?

Comment: The only reason you might not want to do that is performance but I guess it is not so critical in this case.

Comment: @KillerX: It's debatable whether a lookup and comparison would be quicker... more likely reasons might revolve around triggers and logging; but generally speaking, I don't see why one would do this.

Comment: @eggyal: Depends what type of performance we are talking about. If you have a system that for some reason handles writes very badly but is blazingly fast when reading because you have a bunch of read only slaves, it might be better. But what I was mostly thinking about was not wether to drop the SELECT or not but rather about for example storing the old values in session and comparing them when a result comes in. In this case you avoid all the SELECTS as well as unneeded inserts.

Comment: @KillerX: Yes, I had assumed that's what you meant - but one still needs to retrieve the values from session storage and then perform comparisons; with suitable table indexes, it's likely that MySQL will perform this identical set of operations faster than PHP (although one would need to benchmark to be certain) - plus it saves on redundantly repeating those operations a second time if the update is to proceed.

Comment: @eggyal: I see your point now. I guess a lot in this case depends on what the actual data is and how the infrastructure is built up, and if you are willing to invest time/money you could probably always make one approach work better than the other one.

Comment: @ALL: Thank you for cmt.Actually in this case I want to make a system recovery. If the value is in submit the same with the existing value in the database field, record the data is not updated, but if there are changes, the record will be duplicated, the last disubmit who will be active, the previous record will be changed to a data recovery.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother checking. Just make sure the entry is valid and throw it in.

Comment: Actually in this case I want to make a system recovery. If the value is in submit the same with the existing value in the database field, record the data is not updated, but if there are changes, the record will be duplicated, the last disubmit who will be active, the previous record will be changed to a data recovery. Therefore, I need a comparison. Do you have an easy way to do it?

Comment: @Fredy
After sanitizing your form input, something along the lines of:

    `$return = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE data=key LIMIT 1",$connection);

while($value = mysql_fetch_array($return)){
if($otherField == $value['fieldname']){
doRecovery();
}else{
doInsert();
}
}`

Answer (score -1):

Keep two hidden fields with current values of the fields. After submitting the form check whether submitted values are different from the hidden field values.

Comment: User input, even from 'hidden' fields, can not be trusted.